# $each error after copying code

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphael

I have developed a chart using graphael(my question has nothing to do with this), and I am calling an $each function.

When I had my chart at a different project, the function was working fine and the chart was showing correctly. When I copied **exactly the same** code at a different project, I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined
```

Do you know what can be wrong?

Comment: That means `$` is undefined. include jquery in the new project.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks a lot! Someone of my team removed the jquery from the project. Thanks! :) I will upvote it and select it as best answer if you post it as an answer

Comment: i'd suggest just closing the question, but i'll move my comment to an answer if you insist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are attempting to execute `each` as a property of `$` and are getting the following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined
```

we can assume that `$` is undefined. This is often caused by not including the jquery library in your project.